# Parallel repetition to amplify the gap for nonlocal games

Tags: complexity-theory, non-locality, nonlocal-games

Suppose for an one-round nonlocal game $G$ with question size $n$, answer size $2$ (i.e the answer is yes or no), a verifier and two provers Alice and Bob sharing $\text{Poly}(n)$ entangled-qubits. If for any strategy $s$ with winning rate $w$ between Alice and Bob, there exists a new strategy $s'$ in which Alice and Bob only share $\text{Poly}(\log n)$ entangled qubits and achieves a winning rate $w'$, $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\leq w'\leq w,\alpha$ is a constant. The goal is to decide whether the complexity of approximating the best winning rate of $G$ (within constant error) is in $\mathcal{NP}$ or not. That's to say, whether Alice and Bob only need to share $\text{Poly}(\log n)$ to approximate the best winning rate of $G$.

My attempts: If we can promise that the best winning rate of $G$ (achieved by sharing $\text{Poly}(n)$ entangled qubits) is either $>a$ or $<b$, then **parallelly** play the game for $l$ times to amplify the gap, from Raz's parallel repetition theorem and Chernoff bound for threshold voting, the winning rate of new game $w_1$ is either $>1-(1-a)^l$ or $<b^l$. But the question size becomes $n^l$, then the winning rate of the strategy using $\text{Poly}(\log n)$ entangled qubits is either $>(1-(1-a)^l)/n^{\alpha l}$ or $<b^l$, where it is possible that $(1-(1-a)^l)/n^{\alpha l}<b^l$. Are there any methods to avoid that?

Also post at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52773/

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52773/5038, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/32307/510.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. as you yourself commented in the meta post you linked, cross-policy is not outright disallowed on the network, and is pretty much considered fine on this site. Though I personally might be open to changing this policy, it's considered fine here atm

Comment: @glS, thank you for letting me know, I will try to keep that in mind in the future.  The version on the other site has improvements/edits that haven't been reflected here; there is no warning on the other site that it has been cross-posted and no cross-link on the other site, as requested on the MSE post; the question is identical on both sites and has not been tailored to each site, as requested by the MSE post.